# Summming odd and even numbers in an undetermined range

Tags: c++, sum

My assignment is to create a program in which the user inputs a starting value and ending value. The program should then sum all the numbers within that range. In addition it should sum the odd numbers and the even numbers. My issue is determining which numbers in the users range is odd and which is even and then summing these values. The total sum loop works but I have tried multiple other loops for the odd and even sums and have had no success. So if someone could help me sum these numbers based on whether there even or odd.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

int sum = 0, start, endnumber;
int sumall = 0,  c=0;
cout << "Please enter the starting integer\n";
    cin >> start;
cout << "Please enter the ending integer\n";
    cin >> endnumber;
while (endnumber <= start)
{
cout << "Please enter the starting integer\n";
    cin >> start;
cout << "Please enter the ending integer\n";
    cin >> endnumber;
}

    while (start <= endnumber)
{

    sumall = sumall + start;
    ++start;

}
    std::cout << "The sum is: " << sumall << std::endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: To test for odd or even, you need to divide by two and see if the remainder is 0 (even) or 1 (odd). Fortunately, there's a nice little symbol to help you: %. Look up "modulus" in your favourite search engine.

Comment: use the modulo operator... or some math.

Comment: "I have tried multiple other loops for the odd and even sums and have had no success." - show us your attempts.

Comment: Both these sums have analytical solutions. You do not need brute force here.

Comment: I had read about the modulus operator but I was confused how I would then set these values as odd or even and begin the sum. I tried assigning each value to a variable called oddsum or evensum and then adding that to the previous value of oddsum or evensum as it looped through but that did not work.

Comment: please don't talk. post code.

Comment: No need for any loops - just use the difference of `sum{0,n}(odd)` at `n`=start and `n`=end; similarly for the even numbers.  Or even just use the generalized formula for arithmetic progressions.  Don't forget to watch out for integer overflow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check each number in the range with modulo.
For ex:

```
if( start%2 == 0 )  // even
{
    evenSum+=start;
}
else // Odd
{
     oddSum+=start;
}
```

That will do the job.

Comment: I could write a complete example but then you will not really learn, so i posted just the direction, i am sure you'll find the rest.

Comment: Given that this is C++, `?:` evaluates to an lvalue, so `(start%2?oddSum:evenSum)+=start;`.  But I don't recommend handing that in as homework...

Answer (score 0):

You can test for odd numbers by anding with 1.

```
if ((start & 1) == 0)
    evenSum += start;
else
    oddSum += start;
```

Small note when talking to mathematicians: don't use modulo and modulus interchangeably (even though wikipedia says they are the same):

- modulo is % for positive numbers.
- modulus is the abs function.